# jquery toggle didnt toggle and why my background repeat

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im new and i make [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qun3fbz2/) page, but i have 2 problems. I don't wana my backgroind to repeat and my Jquery toggle doesnt work :(

This is part of my code. What i need to change to make it work?

```
body {
    background: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/anna-bg.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.first {
    background: #000;
    background-image: url("http://buddies.koinup.com/group-637.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
p {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: black;
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: justify;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 65px 3px 64px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
    transition: height .5s;
    -webkit-transition: height .5s;
    -moz-transition: height .5s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For background:

```
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

For jQuery: you didn't import the library. The code itself works. Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qun3fbz2/1/

Comment: Ops about that jquery mistake. But i dont wana my background to be only on top, i want this background image to be in whole page. Like this one here https://dash.generalassemb.ly/dddd/build-your-own-personal-website

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
background: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/anna-bg.png");
```

to

```
background: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/anna-bg.png") no-repeat;
```

Because, there is no element in inner Body.The div.first is position absolute. So the body takes less height

Do like this, If you want.

```
<body>
  <div style="min-height:600px;display:block;">
    <div class="first">
```

Comment: hmm still didnt fill whole page. I notice that when i remove <!DOCTYPE html> evrything is ok but when i add it it start that mess :/

Comment: how In fiddle there is no <!DOCTYPE html>?

Comment: Yes. But i write that code first on my pc, and i forgot to write <!DOCTYPE html> it start just with one div 100 x 100 :D. And when i add doctype that background change his properties :/

Comment: Anyway you got an solution. thats okay.

Comment: This is without doctype
http://i.imgur.com/BuawDzu.png

This is with doctype
http://i.imgur.com/13tyg3o.png

Comment: Philip I think html5 tags are not work properly If you not using <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Answer (score 0):

```
body { 
    background: url(http://dash.ga.co/assets/anna-bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;  
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

this is how body css need to be to be all things ok :)

http://jsfiddle.net/PhilipScot/qun3fbz2/3/